# VHDL Misunderstanding about Clock

Tags: vhdl

I have a question about my VHDL code. The code is for a robot, that should be able to detect a  mine. This piece of code is the code for this specific mine detector. The teller_sensor process doesnt work. i know that, since it will be programmed on a FPGA chip, you can only have one clock. But I dont know what to do to make the process work. I hope you guys are willing to help me:)

Roberto

Here is the code:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
library ieee; use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity metaal_detector is
port (clk    : in std_logic;
      sensor : in std_logic;
      reset  : in std_logic;
      metaal : out std_logic
);
end entity metaal_detector;

architecture behavioural of metaal_detector is
signal count, count_sensor, stand, clock1, sensor1, stand1 : unsigned (10 downto 0);
signal reset_teller, resets, metaals: std_logic;

begin

teller_clk: process (clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if ((reset ='1') or (resets = '1')) then
    count <= (others => '0');
  else
    count <= count + 1;
  end if;
end if;
end process;


teller_sensor: process (sensor)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if ((reset ='1') or (resets = '1')) then
    count_sensor <= (others => '0');
  else
    if (sensor'event and sensor='1') then
      count_sensor <= count_sensor + 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
end process;


process(clk)
begin
if (unsigned(clock1) = 71) then
  stand <= clock1;
  reset_teller <= '1';
else
  reset_teller <= '0';
  stand <= stand;
end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin
if (unsigned(stand1) < 70) then
  metaals <= '1';
else
  metaals <= '0';
end if;
end process;


clock1 <= count;
sensor1 <= count_sensor;
stand1 <= stand;
resets <= reset_teller;
metaal <= metaals;

end architecture behavioural;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify clk rather than sensor at the top of the process.  Then sample the state of sensor within, which is to say at the clock edge of interest.

Such an approach is not without theoretical issues (metastability, sampling theory) but it's likely to get you on the path to a degree of functionality.

Right now nothing happens because it only could if a change in sensor triggers the process at the same time that there happens to be a rising edge of clk.  In hardware that would be rare (and not implementable with typical blocks where the edge detector is part of the clock input) - in simulation it may well be impossible (you would have to read the detailed language and simulator rules) but regardless in neither case will it do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I switched sensor for clk in the sensitivity list. However, I dont really understand what you mean with "Then sample the state of the sensor within, which is to say at the clock edge of interest". Could you explain that for me?